# How to convert switch statement to object literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, switch-statement

I am trying to convert a switch statement to object literal in typescript but am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'AllowedAnimals' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'Dog & Horse' was reduced to 'never' because property 'species' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'Dog' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

... with the example code is below. Am I doing my typings incorrectly or is this anti-pattern with Typescript?

```
interface Animal{
    species:string,
    weight:number,
    name:string
}

type AllowedAnimals = Dog |Horse

interface Dog extends Animal{
    species:"dog",
    hasFleas:boolean
}

interface Horse extends Animal{
    species:"horse",
    handsTall:number
}

const processDog = (d:Dog)=>{}

const processHorse = (h:Horse)=>{}

const userInput = "";

const a:AllowedAnimals = JSON.parse(userInput);

switch (a.species){
    case "dog":
        processDog(a);
        break;
    case "horse":
        processHorse(a);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

const objectLiteral = {
    "dog":processDog,
    "horse":processHorse
}

objectLiteral[a.species](a); //<- Error
```

Comment: Typescript is doing fine here. `a` is a value which you're telling typescript is of type `AllowedAnimals` which itself is a union. when you write `objectLiteral[a.species]` typescript doesn't know which one between `dog` or `horse` would be indexed so it can't give you a hint about the function argument.

Comment: Thanks - does this mean it is impossible to do what I wan to do? Should I make it so that 'a' is of type Animal?

Comment: It looks like the type of the literal needs to be the genus (animal) that shares properties with all the species. I then cast within each function to the particular species: processDog(a as Dog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript isn't clever enough to figure out that the type of `objectLiteral[a.species]` is dependent on the concrete type of `a`. All it knows that the property access will come up with `(d: Dog) => void | (h: Horse) => void`, but when you try to call that it will need to unify the argument types, arguing that the argument would need to have a type that can be passed to any of these functions. `(a: Dog & Horse) => void` comes up as `a: never`, as the error message explains.

You can cheat however with an explicit cast:

```
(objectLiteral[a.species] as (a: AllowedAnimal) => void)(a);
```

That way you can satisfy the typechecker. Whether it's a good idea I can't tell - you probably get less complete checks than with `switch`.

```
type process<X extends Animal> = (a: X) => void
const processDog: process<Dog> = _=>{}
const processHorse: process<Horse> = _=>{}

const objectLiteral: {
   [p in AllowedAnimals['species']]: process<AllowedAnimals & {species: p}>
} = {
    "dog": processDog,
    "horse": processHorse
};

let a: AllowedAnimals = null as any;
(objectLiteral[a.species] as process<AllowedAnimals>)(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment:

Typescript is doing fine here. `a` is a value which you're telling typescript is of type `AllowedAnimals` which itself is a union. when you write `objectLiteral[a.species]` typescript doesn't know which one between `dog` or `horse` would be indexed so it can't give you a hint about the function argument.

As you have mentioned in your question, you could benefit from [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) using switch statements to do what you're trying to do:

```
interface Animal{
    species:string,
    weight:number,
    name:string
}

type AllowedAnimals = Dog |Horse

interface Dog extends Animal{
    species:"dog",
    hasFleas:boolean
}

interface Horse extends Animal{
    species:"horse",
    handsTall:number
}

const processDog = (d:Dog)=>{}

const processHorse = (h:Horse)=>{}

const process = (animal : AllowedAnimals) => {
    switch(animal.species) {
        case "dog":
            objectLiteral[animal.species](animal);
            break;
        case "horse":
            objectLiteral[animal.species](animal);
            break;
    }
}

const objectLiteral = {
    "dog":processDog,
    "horse":processHorse
}

const userInput = "";

const a:AllowedAnimals = JSON.parse(userInput);

process(a);
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwN4BQyxyAzgA4QLASkBcpYUoA5gDREkDuEwLAFmDogArpgBG0DiWQg4mCAyasCAXwIEwAT0pocOAPY8AJuiy5SyALzIAIgZbIAPgAkDUUhA2hIsRCntHCAAPSBBjSzNsfE5iCioaegAiYwck6RJ%20OFIAMRwIbLpxAwN8uBA1b3BoeCRkNw8UELCItAxowhl46lo6JP53T3TY5Czw0gAVXBxhMUkoSoIEAxBGZHIoAyRSUkDrZAAKYzpAgEorAD48dSWVtY2t2lIGz32D-joXiHOrm%20XVsDrTbbSw2A7lcw4ZB0PSGExRCynawXZCdEikLjAMAIfjg9q4AB03USSLRMmICGyKBSaToI3JJAM4gAVlQwAAZLHQXAAbQh0SJlB6pAAunjIacANz0hnIcRQAoAa2lsuQlNe-UGECSdNVMiZrIQHK5UF5-MJxNoYvNOClMoZ8qVKpI6j%20d0BBrZnN8uH2ZOQNJYOoeIMCGWImsaweBTy%20i3%20axEnigAEkQOQRICbEkktLbgDkHA6Kh9EYIKZ8ThQcgAFIAZQA8gA5AnkOCNA5J6BpjNgO0EENPcH9oA)

Comment: Yes, the OP knows that (see the example code in the question). That's what they want to get *away* from.

Comment: @Bergi tbh I didn't really understand what kind of alternative the OP is looking for. I already explained in my comment why the code in the question predictably doesn't work.

Comment: They want to know how to teach typescript to understand that the code does work. If it is not possible, an explanation of the why should be the answer (and a link to the respective ticket in the typescript issue tracker - which usually exists - can serve as evidence).

Comment: Thank you for your comments and explanation. I am trying to avoid a switch statement altogether though so I accepted Bergis answer